# Hash/Array of objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, hash

I'm pretty new to Ruby (I come from a C++ background) and I have an array/hash of objects by their name but I'm having no luck when trying to access their variables. This is my attempt:

```
class Foo
attr_reader :num

def initialize(num)
    @num = num
end
end

foo_list = {}

foo_list["one"] = Foo.new("124")
foo_list["two"] = Foo.new("567")

foo_list.each do |foo|
p "#{foo.num}"              # ERROR: undefined method 'num'
end
```

I'm pretty sure there is an easy way of doing what I need, maybe not even using 'each' but something else?

Comment: Just a word of advice, you can print out `foo` in the block to see what `foo` actually is. Also, Ruby documentation is pretty good. Just googling for "ruby hash" then looking up the `each` method, would have put you on the right track. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each

Comment: Or, if you let Ruby build its built-in documentation, `ri Hash` at the command-line would show the various methods. `ri Hash.each` would have given more information specific to `each`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't that be `foo_list.each do |key, foo|`, given that `foo_list` is a hash?

Comment: OMG, I feel stupid, there goes an hour of my life on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You might be looking for this:

```
foo_list.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key}: #{value}"
end
```

Or you can extend your own example (foo would be an array here containing the key and value):

```
foo_list.each do |foo|
  puts "#{foo[0]}: #{foo[1]}"
end
```

Or you could do this without the each:

```
puts "one: #{foo_list["one"]}"
puts "two: #{foo_list["two"]}"
```

Have fun learning Ruby! :-)